# How to create a new record rule in odoo10 for manager?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, record-rules

If x is the manager of a and y is the manager of b then in project module of odoo-10 x can see only the project assigned to a and y can see the project assigned  to b.how can i write this new record rule for manager.

Comment: there are so many questions and solutions available for these type of question, kindly check the google before asking a question@subhashree

Answer (score 1):

Create record rule like below:

```xml
<record model="ir.rule" id="project_manager_see_assigned">
    <field name="name">Project: project manager: see assigned project</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_project_project"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('project.group_project_manager'))]"/>
</record>
```

Note: By default, there is a record rule which allows the manager to see all projects. Either remove or modify before create it.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting, in developer mode under technical menu, you will see record rules. Firstly create a user and remove all the rights. Give him the menu from the user in user menu.
Then login from the user and open that menu. Start your work cycle and you will face many access rights error. Start adding them one by one whenever you face them.
This way you will create perfect record rules for a manager. He wont see any unnecessary menu and options.